# Exception in Tkinter callback When you press button 1 again

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem asking for your help, I'm doing opencv based face detection, it's done step by step.
1. Get information of person based on id
2. take the person's face
3. Training
After I got the information of the first person, I did step 2 to get that person's face
Next is to get the information of the second person, but it failed in the part where the 2nd person's face was.
How can I fix it, please help me

```
        enter code here` db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
        db.set_converter_class(NumpyMySQLConverter)
        
        # connect to mysql
        def get_db():
            global db
            if db.is_connected():
                pass
            else:
                db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
        def insertOrUpdate():
            # ket noi db
            # kiem tra id nhap vao ton tai hay chua ?
            get_db()
            cid = ent.get()
            cname = ent2.get()
            birthday = ent7.get_date()
            ccountry = ent4.get()
            carea = ent5.get()
            cphone = ent6.get()
            if (cid == "" or cname == "" or birthday=="" or ccountry=="" or carea==""):
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "field is not empty")
            # cphone = re.compile(r'^(?:\+?44)?[07]\d{9,13}$')
            # if not cphone.search():
            #     messagebox.showinfo("Error", "field is not empty")
            mycursor = db.cursor()
            sql = ("select * from db_people WHERE id="+ str(cid))
            mycursor.execute(sql,cid)
            myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
            print(myresult)
            isRecordExist = 0
            # duyet hang tren bang ghi
            for row in myresult:
                print("chay khong")
                isRecordExist =1
            print(isRecordExist)
            if(isRecordExist == 0):
                # cid = ent.get()
                # cname=ent2.get()
                # birthday = ent7.get_date()
                # ccountry = ent4.get()
                # carea =ent5.get()
                # cphone= ent6.get()
                # print(cid)
                if(radio.get() =="Male"):
                    sql = "INSERT INTO db_people(id,user_name,gender,dateOfBirth,country,area,phone) 
                           VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                    val = (cid, cname, str(radio.get()), birthday,ccountry, carea, cphone)
                else:
                    sql = "INSERT INTO db_people(id,user_name,gender,dateOfBirth,country,area,phone) 
                           VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                    val = (cid, cname, str(radio.get()), birthday,ccountry, carea, cphone)
            else:
                query = "UPDATE db_people SET user_name='" + str(user_name)+"' WHERE id=" + str(cid)
        
            print("done")
            # thuc thi lenh
            mycursor.execute(sql,val)
            db.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo("Message", "Success")
            db.close()
        
           # load thu vien opencv
           face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+ 
           "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
           cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        
        # UI
        win = Tk()
        
        frame = tk.Frame(master=win, width=400, height=800)
        frame.pack()
        label0 = tk.Label(master=frame, text="Employee Infomation ")
        label0.place(x=100, y=20)
        
        
        id = StringVar()
        c_id = StringVar()
        label1 = Label(frame,textvariable=id)
        id.set("Enter id")
        label1.place(x =0 ,y =60)
        ent = Entry(frame,textvariable=c_id,width=40)
        ent.place(x =70 , y=60)
        
        
        user_name = StringVar()
        c_name = StringVar()
        label2 = Label(frame,textvariable=user_name)
        user_name.set("Enter name")
        label2.place(x =0 ,y =100)
        ent2 = Entry(frame,textvariable=c_name,width=40)
        ent2.place(x =70 , y=100)
        
        
        gender = StringVar()
        radio = tk.StringVar()
        label3 = Label(frame,textvariable=gender)
        gender.set("Gender")
        label3.place(x =0 ,y =140)
        r1 = Radiobutton(win,text="Male",variable= radio,value="Male")
        r1.pack()
        r1.place(x =120 , y=140)
        r2 = Radiobutton(win,text="Female",variable= radio,value="Female")
        r2.pack()
        r2.place(x =180 , y=140)
        
        dayOfbirh = StringVar()
        c_birth = 'm/d/y'
        label7 = Label(frame,textvariable=dayOfbirh)
        dayOfbirh.set("DayOfBirth")
        label7.place(x =0 ,y =180)
        
        ent7 = DateEntry(frame,date_pattern=c_birth,background="blue",foreground="white",borderwidth = 
               2,width=37)
        ent7.place(x =70 ,y =180)
        
        
        area = StringVar()
        c_area = StringVar()
        label5 = Label(frame,textvariable=area)
        area.set("Work place")
        label5.place(x =0 ,y =220)
        ent5 = Entry(frame,textvariable=c_area,width=40)
        ent5.place(x =70 ,y =220)
        
        country = StringVar()
        c_country = StringVar()
        label4 = Label(frame,textvariable=country)
        country.set("Address")
        label4.place(x =0 ,y =300)
        ent4 = Entry(frame,textvariable=c_country,width=40)
        ent4.place(x =70 ,y =300)
        
        phone = StringVar()
        c_phone = StringVar()
        label6 = Label(frame,textvariable=phone)
        phone.set("Phone")
        label6.place(x =0 ,y =260)
        ent6 = Entry(frame,textvariable=c_phone,width=40)
        ent6.place(x =70 ,y =260)
        
        def Trainning():
            import trainData
        def logout():
            import detect_mask_video
            # win.destroy()
            # import login
        # lay db tu camera
        def opencam():
            sampleNum = 0
            while(True):
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                # chuyen anh thanh mau xam de training
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3, 5)
        
                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    # tao folder dataset va kiem tra
                    if os.path.exists('dataset/image_trainning'):
                        sampleNum += 1
                    id = c_id.get()
                    cv2.imwrite('dataset/image_trainning/User.' + str(id) + '.' + str(sampleNum) + 
                     '.jpg', gray[y: y + h, x: x + w])
        
                cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
        
                if sampleNum > 10:
                    break;
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        btn1 = Button(frame,text="1.Get Infor", command=insertOrUpdate).place(x =5 ,y =350)
        btn3 = Button(frame,text="3.Trainning", command=Trainning).place(x =170 ,y =350)
        btn4 = Button(frame,text="4.Camera", command=logout).place(x =260 ,y =350)
        btn2 = Button(frame,text="2.Get Image", command=opencam).place(x =80 ,y =350)
        win.title("Information employee")
        win.geometry("490x400")
        win.resizable(False,False)
        win.mainloop()


this is error: 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/bk/Capstone2_backup/getData.py", line 183, in opencam
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-j8nxabm_\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: What does "it failed" mean? How did it fail? Did it throw an error? If so, what was the error? Please try to reduce the code in the question down to a [mcve]

Comment: Bryan Oakley  - the error I wrote down at the end of the code, I don't know the cause of the error, because when I get the information of the first person it still works, but when I get the information of the 2nd person it doesn't work . I think it got a bug with facial image capture but I don't know how to fix it